# Rails caching techniques for a personalized news feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, feed, cache-expiration

In a scenario where there are users that have posts, and each user has a view representing a news feed (much like with a logged in Tumblr account), and each post overview has a link to the comments with a comment counter per post, what is the best caching strategy here (On a Rails 4 stack)?

Assuming 5 users, A B C D E, with each being subscribed to the 2 users on their right (A is subscribed to B and C, B is subscribed to C and D etc.) and only having the users they've subscribed to showing up on their news feed view.

Edit:

Assume a fan-out-on-write approach is taken, where each user has a unique set (of post ids) in Redis, and on every `post` create, the id of the new post is appended to every of the post creator's friends' sets. The redis sets act as an index and a user's feed is fetched via a single SQL query.

Bearing this in mind, caching each feed should be a matter of this approach:

1. Check set in redis (first hit)
2. write `@feed_array` to memcached
3. fetch posts with single SQL command and save to `@feed`
4. write `@feed` to memcached
5. Check set in redis (second hit)
6. If set values match `@feed_array` then return `@feed` from memcached. Otherwise new SQL query and override `@feed` in memcached

This approach would mean easy cache use for the views when iterating through the `@post` divs, but how would one handle the comment counts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unrelated of the application stack that you are using, i don't think that a caching approach scales in your situation. twitter-like functionality is often handled by de-normalization.

in your situation, this could mean implementing a feed model for each user, appending new posts of the followers, so that it is fast to load the 'timeline' of a user from his own feed, instead of joining all his (possible thousands) of friends.

Comment: Even with the fan-out-on-write approach you suggest, a caching approach will still be necessary. If a user has a 'timeline' from a `Feed` model and say @feed = Feed.where(etc.) then the feed item divs will still need to be delivered cached, and the problem is the comment counters. How to deal with those?

Comment: @railsuser400 i don't think that there is THE ANSWER for you. it all depends on your requirements. for a responsive solution, caching might not even be involved. you could IE load stuff (comment counts or whatever) via javascript, or take a single page approach with a javascript MVC.